# How do references in functions work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, reference

First I wrote the first sample of code and it didn't work correctly. I prefer the first sample, but only the second one works correctly. I don't know why the first sample doesn't change the original array but second does. Where is the difference?

**First sample:**

```
import heapq

def heap_sort(tab):
    heap = []
    for i in tab:
        heapq.heappush(heap, i)
    tab = [heapq.heappop(heap) for _ in xrange(len(heap))]

temp_tab = [4, 3, 5, 1]
heap_sort(temp_tab)
print temp_tab
```

Prints:

```
[4, 3, 5, 1]
```

---

**Second sample:**

```
import heapq

def heap_sort(tab):
    heap = []
    for i in tab:
        heapq.heappush(heap, i)
    for i, _ in enumerate(tab):
        tab[i] = heapq.heappop(heap)

temp_tab = [4, 3, 5, 1]
heap_sort(temp_tab)
print temp_tab
```

Prints:

```
[1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: In the first example, if you had assigned to `tab[:]` instead of `tab`, it would have worked.

Comment: What's the point of this code? Why don't you return heap instead of pushing everything back into tab? In fact, why not just sort the list and forget about the heap stuff altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use `[:]`, that will change the original object passed in:

```
def heap_sort(tab):
    heap = []
    for i in tab:
        heapq.heappush(heap, i)
    tab[:] = [heapq.heappop(heap) for _ in xrange(len(heap))]
```

So instead of reassigning the name `tab` to a new object you are actually updating the original `tab` object.

You could also use a generator expression instead of building the whole list:

```
tab[:] = (heapq.heappop(heap) for _ in xrange(len(heap)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're just reassigning a new name called `tab` inside the function, it doesn't affect the global name `tab` you've defined.
So, change your function to actually return the value, will work:

```
import heapq

def heap_sort(tab):
    heap = []
    for i in tab:
        heapq.heappush(heap, i)
    # return the supposed tab value
    return [heapq.heappop(heap) for _ in xrange(len(heap))]

tab = [4, 3, 5, 1]
# assign the tab to the returned value
tab = heap_sort(tab)
print tab
[1, 3, 4, 5]
```

For your reference, read [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) will help you understand how the referencing works in Python.

Comment: But If I have different name (tab1 whatever) the results is the same.

Comment: @WuJo, The key is that, inside the function, they have no access to the global `tab`, it's just creating a new name called `tab`, once the function returns, that new `tab` value is disposed.

Comment: @WuJo, so instead you reassign your global `tab` to the returned value from the function, will work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
>>> def heap_sort(tab):
    heap=[]
    for i in tab:
        heapq.heappush(heap,i)
    heapq.heapify(heap)
    return heap

>>> t=heap_sort(t)
>>> print(t)
[1, 3, 5, 4]
```