# What does this notation do for lists in Python: "someList[:]"?

Tags: python, list, slice, notation, shallow-copy

I sometimes get across this way of printing or returning a list - `someList[:]`.
I don't see why people use it, as it returns the full list.

Why not simply write `someList`, whithout the `[:]` part?

Comment: are you referring to any specific language?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explain Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of either question, although both contain an implicit answer.

Comment: You may check my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884268/how-do-references-in-functions-work
[:] helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`[:]` creates a slice, usually used to get just a part of a list. Without any minimum/maximum index given, it creates a copy of the entire list. Here's a Python session demonstrating it:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b1 = a
>>> b2 = a[:]
>>> b1.append(50)
>>> b2.append(51)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 50]
>>> b1
[1, 2, 3, 50]
>>> b2
[1, 2, 3, 51]
```

Note how appending to `b1` also appended the value to `a`. Appending to `b2` however did not modify `a`, i.e. `b2` is a copy.

Comment: Thanks, Frerich, I get it now. In those cases I came across [:] was indeed used for making a copy of a list.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that this creates a *shallow* copy of the list, so the pattern can run into problems if you have, eg, lists of lists.

Comment: From an "explicit is better than implicit" point of view, it might be better to ``import copy`` and using ``copy.copy(lst)`` instead. The slice notation doesn't hint at what it does and is hard to google.

Answer (score 16):

In python, when you do `a = b`, a doesn't take the *value* of b, but *references* the same value referenced by b. To see this, make:

```
>>> a = {'Test': 42}
>>> b = a
>>> b['Test'] = 24
```

What is now the value of a?

```
>>> a['Test']
24
```

It's similar with lists, so we must find a way to really *copy* a list, and not *make a reference* to it. One way could be to recreate the list `copy = list(list1)`, or use the functions of the `copy` module. But, after all, the easiest way, the prettiest, the best way ( ;) ) for doing this, is to copy each value of the first list to the other, by doing `copy = list1[:]`. It uses the slices, here list1 is sliced from index 0 to index len(list1), so the whole list1 is returned!

Moreover, the slice method is slightly faster: using the time.clock() method to measure the mean execution time of 1000 assignment of lists, each one containing 10000 random integers, with slices, constructor and deepcopy, the results show that the slices are 15% faster than the constructor method, and deepcopy is 4 times slower. However, this gain of time is negligible while using small lists: thus, using `copy = list(list_to_copy)` or `copy = list_to_copy[:]` is up to the developer's preferences.

Finally, we often forget the list.copy method, which seems to be the faster! In fact, it's even 13% faster than the slice method!

Comment: "(for mutable objects...)": to be clear, `b = a` works exactly the same way if `a` is mutable or if `a` is immutable.

Comment: I think `the easiest way, the prettiest, the best way` is fairly subjective (and I disagree, I like `list(a)` better than `a[:]`).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Yes, it's willingly subjective, that's why I used that much superlatives, and the smiley to emphasize this

Comment: The answer is wrong IMHO. `a = b` doesn't create a reference to _b_ but to the value referenced by _b_.  After the assignment both names reference the same value. In fact every name in Python references a value, so even copying the list before assignment leads to a reference — to the new list object. Objectively speaking `list(L)` is easier to look up in the docs than `L[:]` and it is much more flexible because `L` can be anything that's _iterable_ and not just objects that support slicing. It works even with objects that don't implement slicing at all.

Comment: I use to know this 6-7 years ago! Lol

Comment: `list` also has a `copy` method since Python 3.3.

Comment: @Veedrac Thanks, I've forgotten this one, and after some tests, it's the fastest way!

Answer (score 8):

To **create a copy** of a list instead of passing by reference, as Python does. Use next two example to understand the difference.

**Example:**

```
# Passing by reference
SomeListA = [1, 2, 3]
SomeListB = [2, 3, 4]
SomeListB = SomeListA
SomeListA[2] = 5
print SomeListB
print SomeListA

# Using slice
SomeListA = [1, 2, 3]
SomeListB = [2, 3, 4]
SomeListB = SomeListA[:]
SomeListA[2] = 5
print SomeListB
print SomeListA
```

Answer (score 4):

When you need to modify the list and you don't want to change the list and create another list you use

```
y = [1,2,3]
x = y[:]
```

and you can do a lot of changes to the list but the origin list will be in (y) and the modified in (x)

Answer (score -1):

#Here is a simpler way for beginners to understand:

```
list16 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list17 = list16[:]
```

#^Identifying that 'list17' is a copy of 'list16' and not list16 directly

```
list17[0] = 10
```

#^ Making an alteration in the new copied list

```
print(list17)
print(list16)
= [10,2,3,4,5,6]
= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

#Printing the lists so that you can see what is happening. I created a copy of the list and altered it without changing the original list at all.

Answer (score -2):

There are 2 copies available. 1) Deep Copy 2) Shallow Copy.
1) Deep Copy is you just copy the values
`list = ['abc',123,'xyz']`
`list1 = copy.deepcopy(list) or list1 = list[:]`

2) Shallow Copy is you just reference to the varible
`list2 = copy.copy(list) or list2 = list`

When you modify something on list2 it get effected in list also as it is referenced.
`list1.append(456)`
`list2.append('789')`
`print "list: %s" %list`
`print "list1: %s" %list1`
`print "list2: %s" %list2`
ans:
`list : ['abc',123,'xyz','789']`
`list1 : ['abc',123,'xyz',456]`
`list2 : ['abc',123,'xyz','789']`